# C#: Serialize object vs create new XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Which solution is better for creating XML?

Create a model xml document, fill it out and then use:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(xmlModel.GetType());
        StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

        ns.Add("", "");
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, xmlModel, ns);

        string xmlString = sww.ToString();
```

Or manually create the xml file, eg:

```
XDocument xml =
            new XDocument(
                new XElement("el1",
                    new XAttribute("xcv", xcv),
                    new XAttribute("cvb", cvb ?? string.Empty),
                    new XAttribute("vbn", vbn ?? string.Empty),
                    new XAttribute("bnm", bnm),
                    new XAttribute("nm", dnm),
```

...

I know that the solution of 1 requires less code, but I can trust .net serialization?

Comment: This question doesn't really fit with stackoverflow rules. Its too general. Do you have a specific reason not to trust .net serialization? Also what makes you think you can "trust" the XDocument approach?  I've used serialization extensively and it uses little code, is very maintainable, extensible and easy to read. It does mean you have to follow certain rules when designing your xml but I've never found that to be an issue.

Comment: This is too general. What are you looking for? parsing flexibility? speed? you should also think about maintainability differences between these two.

Comment: You're right, the question is too general. I care for correct operation, a project is very serious, All xml is generated as example 2, but I do not like this solution. So I ask whether .Net serialization is stable, there is some hidden pitfalls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used .NET serialization on many occurances and I did not face any serious problems, but this does not necessarily mean that you won't. There might be may other developers that see the .NET's serilization as a pitfall.

In my humble opinion I find .NET's serialization quite satisfactory and easy to use. Although I used XDocument only recently I found it quite easy to use to query XML files but can't provide any feedback on creating documents.

P.S. : Please let me ask if there is a special case that you might face while creating XML documents, that might cause trouble using .NET's serialization?